# How to make variables used in read global for the script

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I want to read a file with the data ordered in column.
In the script that I'm writing I use the `read` command.

The input file is made by lines like the following:

```
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   PQRTS
YY:YY:YY:YY:YY   ABCDE
ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ   FGHIJ
```

What I'm using to read it is something  like this

```
while read a b; do 
echo $a
echo $b
done < filename.txt
```

Till now it reads line by line and assigns  `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` to `a`  and `PQRTS` to `b` in first iteration of the `while` cycle, after  `YY:YY:YY:YY:YY` to `a` and `ABCDE` to `b` in the second iteration, and so on.

Now my questions are:

1. How can I use `a` and `b` as global variables?
2. I want to assign `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`, `YY:YY:YY:YY:YY` so that I can use them in different functions.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "global variables"? You could just assign `$a` to something else in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`bash arrays`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html)
For your purpose you can write a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read a[$i] b[$i]; do 
  echo ${a[$i]}                # Print the current one a
  echo ${b[$i]}                # Print the current one b 
  i=$[ i+1 ]                   # Increment i
done < filename.txt  
#  do other stuffs...          # if you want
echo "$[ $i -1 ] Items read "  # The number of lines read
echo The second a was ${a[1]}  # Array starts from 0
echo Those are all b  ${b[*]}  # You can print all together
```

1. It depends from what you mean for `global`. Sadly you cannot simply `export` them outside of your script. From the `man bash` on  `bash 4.3.11(1)-release` you can read.

   > Array variables may not (yet) be exported.
2. Inside your script you can use the array as normal variable. Instead of `echo $a` you have to refer to them with something like `echo ${a[0]}` or `echo ${b[2]}`...
   Note that you need to put `{}` to protect them.